# ORA-01012 Error. What is the Windows counterpart for SYSRESV?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I encountered an **ORA-01012 NOT LOGGED ON** error. (Oracle 11g)

I saw some posts that I need to remove the orphaned shared memory segment using **sysresv** utility and **ipcrm -m**. But found out this is only applicable to Linux. We are using Windows Server 2012 R2 Server.

1. Does Windows Server have a counterpart for sysresv & ipcrm utility? OR
2. Is there other way to solve this ORA-01012 issue?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know if there are counterpart for sysresv and ipcrm on Windows but I don't think that you need them because on Windows Oracle Database is a multithreaded process that does not use shared memory (whereas on UNIX Oracle Database is by default non multithreaded - each session is a OS process instead of a thread- and it does use shared memory).
2. ORA-1012 can have a lot root causes: incorrect ORACLE_SID, too many processes connected to database instance, etc. Try to doublecheck ORACLE_SID, ORACLE_HOME and look for errors in database instance alert log.